# FHIR server case sensitivity

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm looking at various client libraries and wondering how they handle imperfections in the various server implementations.

I can see that when it comes to URIs and other things some servers are more forgiving than others.

What about more deeply in to the resources themselves ....
If for example a server was returning donotperform instead of   doNotPerform.

Has anyone any experience of this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't necessarily speak to specific client libraries, but per the FHIR spec, case sensitivity is the general rule. [Search parameters](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#Summary) and [resource/element names](https://hl7.org/fhir/formats.html#table) (see under the Notes) are case-sensitive, and clients should correct the case of search parameters. [Resource IDs](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/resource.html#id) are also case-sensitive.

So, generally speaking, a server should be returning data with respect to the case defined in the spec.

Comment: That said, servers are allowed to be more flexible.  So a server *can* opt to ignore case where it decides this will be beneficial to interoperability.  Clients can't ever count on a server doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity is highly dependent on context.  If you are looking at search, the case-sensitivity rules are generally based on the search type.  For example:

- [string](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#string) by default is case-insensitive, but you can use the `exact` modifier to perform case-sensitive searches.
- [token](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#token) is *generally* considered case-sensitive, but it does depend on the underlying data (e.g., searches against `CodeSystem` and `ValueSet` need to follow the [CodeSystem.caseSensitive](http://hl7.org/fhir/codesystem-definitions.html#CodeSystem.caseSensitive) value).
- [uri](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#uri) is *generally* case-sensitive, but is supposed to follow the rules for each system (e.g., in HTTP URLs, the domain name is case-insensitive while the path is case-sensitive).

When interpreting a *value* present in a resource, it is dependent on the element type.  For example, a code needs to obey the same [CodeSystem.caseSensitive](http://hl7.org/fhir/codesystem-definitions.html#CodeSystem.caseSensitive) value.

Technically `Extension.url` is a `uri`, but do not think I have ever seen a system that treated extension urls as anything other than case-sensitive.

From a developer perspective, I generally try to follow the: be as permissible as possible in what you accept and correct as possible in what you make.  So even in cases where matches are case-sensitive, I try to fallback to a case-insensitive match if case-sensitive fails.  On the other hand, I try and generate everything with the original case, even if it is case-insensitive.

Hope this helps!